# How can I use the function `count` inside an `iterate` form?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I just realized that using the `count` function in `iterate` is awkward. Something like:

```
(iterate (for x below 5) 
         (collect (count x '(1 4 2 3 4 2 1 2))))
```

causes an error (because `iterate` has a `count` clause)  and needs to be rewritten as:

```
(iterate (for x below 5) 
         (collect (funcall #'count x '(1 4 2 3 4 2 1 2))))
```

This made me wish `iterate` stuck to `counting`, `finding`, etc., and left `count`, `find`, etc., alone. But maybe I'm just not seeing the right way of doing this. Is there a better way to use `count` from inside an `iterate` form?

Comment: The manual only describes `counting`, not `count`.

Comment: What iterate implementation are you using? The manual I checked is https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/index.html#Top but it says the macro is named `iter`, not `iterate`.

Comment: Note that Iterate is not part of the CL standard, it's a third-party library.

Comment: @Barmar, the manual you linked also mentions the `iterate` name for the macro in a footnote, saying "You can also use `iterate`, but `iter` is preferred because it avoids potential conflicts with possible future additions to Common Lisp". I actually tend to use `iter` in my own code, I'm not sure why I went with `iterate` here. But both are the same macro.

Comment: @Barmar  `count` and `counting` are synonymous (as are `sum` and `summing`, etc.). For example `(iter (for x below 5) (count (oddp x)))` returns 2.

Comment: The basic problem is that `iterate` uses a code walker to transform the body, and it can't easily distinguish between calls to real functions and uses of its internal keywords. The latter takes precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason someone long ago added a synonym for `count`. This clashes with `cl:count`.

We can remove the synonym:

```
CL-USER 14 > (remprop 'iterate::count 'iterate::synonym)
(ITERATE::SYNONYM COUNTING)

CL-USER 15 > (iterate (for x below 5) 
               (collect (cl:count x '(1 4 2 3 4 2 1 2))))
(0 2 3 1 2)
```

The ITERATE manual is in conflict with the current `iterate` implementation:

[2.3 Gathering Clauses](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/Gathering-Clauses.html#Gathering-Clauses)

> These clauses all begin with a verb. When the verb does not conflict
>   with an existing Common Lisp function, then it may be used in either
>   its infinitival or present-participle form (e.g. sum, summing).
>   However, when there is a conflict with Common Lisp, only the
>   present-participle form may be used (e.g. unioning). This is to
>   prevent iterate clauses from clashing with Common Lisp functions.

Could be useful to report a bug: either remove the synonym(s) in question or fix the documentation. When fixing the documentation it might be useful to document how to use `cl:count` inside an iterate clause.

Comment: I've sent a bug repot to the mailing list and cc'd you. Thanks for explaining this to me!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `loop`?

```
(loop for x below 5
      collect (count x '(1 4 2 3 4 2 1 2)))
```

Somehow even to use `common-lisp:count` inside `iterate` doesn't help.

I would do then:

```
(defun count-it (x list) (count x list))

(iter (for x below 5)
      (collect (count-it x '(1 4 2 3 4 2 1 2))))
```

But then, your `funcall` solution is more elegant even ...

Comment: `loop` is nicer for this case for sure, but I'd still like to know what `iterate` users do to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you have just to make sure 'count' not from 'iter' is taken ...

Comment: strange - although `(common-lisp:count 2 '(1 2 2 3))` works, inside `iterate` it doesn't help ....

Comment: `iterate` must be using string comparison in its code walker, because if it exported names like `count` they would cause name conflicts with the `common-lisp` equivalents.